# Using meta tags with PHP for search engines

Tags: php, mysql, html, seo

I have a site and there are more than 100 folders and files. For search engines,meta tags are very important. So,instead of using meta tag as html like :

```
    <meta name="keywords" content="html,php,seo" />
```

can I use this with PHP like:

```
   <?php 
   $sql ="SELECT keywords FROM database";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<meta name='keywords' content='{$row['keywords']}' />" . ",";
```

For search engines, are both codes same to be indexed?

Comment: "For search engines,meta tags are very important" is not quite right anymore.

Comment: I can't help the sneaky feeling that the author thinks the PHP code is seen by the search engine...

Comment: results are same but I heard that for search engines first code is more important but i am not sure

Comment: 1. This question is off-topic 2. Navigate to your site, click "View Source" or the equivalent in your browser, and check what you see. Basically that's what the Google bot sees.

Comment: i said that it is not different. I asked only for search engines. A seo book writer said first code is more reliable .

Comment: @kalaba2003 I am unsure what he meant by this "first code" thing, it's quite hard to understand out of context. But PHP code is certainly not visible to the Google bot, because the server only serves the HTML generated by your PHP code. It is of course "less reliable" if one writes unreliable PHP code.

Comment: first code means that <meta name="keywords" content="php,seo,html" />.... second code is the code which i write with php.

Comment: @kalaba2003 My question was what the author of the book meant by first code. I don't know which book, but as I see it, most books on SEO are either outdated or simply trash. People don't really write HTML sites with their bare hands anymore (for anything bigger than a few pages at least). They are generated by some means. So in the sense you ask, "first code" and "second code" are not valid terms.

Answer (score 1):

search engines don't see php code, only the html result

Answer (score 1):

with your code we have:

```
<meta name='keywords' content='html' />,
<meta name='keywords' content='php' />,
<meta name='keywords' content='seo' />,
```

I suggest:

```
<?php 
   $sql ="SELECT keywords FROM database";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $keywords = '';
   while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $keywords .= $row['keywords'].',';
   }
   echo "<meta name='keywords' content='$keywords' />";
```

Answer (score 0):

These two codes will send quite the same HTML text to the user's browser, so the answer is: yes, both codes are the same from an SEO point of view.

Comment: why so? could you be more specific?

Comment: @radu That would mean that there is only one set of keywords for the whole site, stored comma-separated in one record. Terrible database design, but possible. Did not think about that :).